# Making a recursive method with triple fibonacci in Java

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have my code down here which is a variation of the fibonacci recursive method. I'm trying to get the right n value to display but it's simply not working... I'm always off by one place in the triple Fibonacci (meaning  triple Fibonacci numbers are inspired by Fibonacci numbers but start with three predetermined values, each value afterwards being the sum of the preceding three values instead of 2 in Fibonacci)

```
public long BinaryOddonacci(int n){
    if (n<=2){ // If the n is 0,1 or 2 the answer is 1
        return 1;
    }
    else {return BinaryOddonacci(n-1) + BinaryOddonacci(n-2) + BinaryOddonacci(n-3);} // recursive call
}
```

The output i should be getting for BinaryOddonacci(10) is 105, but I keep getting 193, which is what I should be getting for BinaryOddonacci(11)...

Comment: "it's simply not working... I'm always off by one place in the triple Fibonacci " Please give a concrete example. What is the actual output and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice   Added!

Comment: Let's back up to something a little simpler. What should `BinaryOddonacci(3)` be? What do you actually get?

Comment: Why is the result 1 for input 0? For normal Fibonacci, this result is 0 for input 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, you set the 0th, 1st, and 2nd value to 1 (per this comment `// If the n is 0,1 or 2 the answer is 1`). So the sequence is as below:

```
0 :  1
1 :  1
2 :  1
3 :  3
4 :  5
5 :  9
6 :  17
7 :  31
8 :  57
9 :  105
10 :  193
```

In other words, `BinaryOddonacci(10)` should return 193, which is what it is returning. There is no error here.